# My Multidimensional Array program isn't populating properly, what am I missing?

Tags: c, arrays, multidimensional-array

I'm writing a program for class that sorts an array of numbers from a text file, and it outputs the highest snowfall, second highest snowfall, and the total range of snowfall.

It's working, mostly. But I'm having an issue with the program outputting the correct amount of inches and second highest snowfall.

that .txt file has this inside of it

```
2017   180.00
2016   176.50
2015   181.50
2014   208.75
2013   225.75
2012   132.00
2011   178.50
2010    150.50
2009    217.00
2008    185.25
2007    162.75
2006    219.50
2005    164.71
2004    232.00
2003    228.00
2002    254.00
2001    303.60
2000    155.00
1999    231.00
1998    131.50
1997    253.10
1996    328.20
1995    175.90
1994    185.30
1993    159.60
1992    166.20
1991    165.80
```

```
//Block comment with name, date, program description

#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

// include other header files that you need

#define MAX_SIZE 100 //can go back 100 years if necessary
#define t 1
#define num 20

int ReadFile (int data1[], double data2[]);
int HighestSnow(double data[], int size);
int NextHighestSnow (double data[], int size, int Highest);
double Range (double data[], int size);

int main (void)

{
    int Year[MAX_SIZE];
    double Snow[MAX_SIZE],SnowfallRange;
    int FileLength, IndexHighest, IndexNextHighest;
    int i;

//Describe code
//Read file using function

    FileLength = ReadFile(Year,Snow);

    for(i = 0; i < FileLength; i++)
        printf("The year for the highest snowfall is: [%d] at %lg\n", Year[IndexHighest], Snow[IndexHighest]);

//Print out data in two columns with first being year and second
//being snowfall in inches

    IndexHighest = HighestSnow(Snow,FileLength);

        printf("The year for the highest snowfall is: [%d] at %lg\n", Year[IndexHighest], Snow[IndexHighest]);

//Print out the year and amount of the highest snowfall

    IndexNextHighest = NextHighestSnow(Snow, FileLength, IndexHighest);

        printf("The year for the second highest snowfall is: [%d] at %lg\n", Year[IndexNextHighest], Snow[IndexNextHighest]);

//Print out the year and amount of the next highest snowfall

    SnowfallRange = Range(Snow,FileLength);

        printf("The snow range is: %lg\n", SnowfallRange);

//Print out the range of snowfall (Max-Min) in inches.

    return 0;

}

//Code for part 1 goes here, include ALL error checks.
int ReadFile (int data1[], double data2[])
{
    FILE *f; //Step 1: Declaring a file pointer

    f = fopen("snowfall.txt", "r"); //Step 2: opening a file

    if(f == NULL) //Step 3: checking to see if the file exists
    {
        printf("File does not exit\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    int i;

    for(i = 0; fscanf(f,"%d %lf ", &data1[i], &data2[i]) == 2; i++); //Step 4: read the values

    fclose(f);

    return i;
}

// Code for part 2 goes here
int HighestSnow(double data[], int size)
{
    int i, index;
    double max = data [0];

    for (i = 1; i < size; i++)
    {
        if (data[i] > max)
        {
            max = data[i];
            index = i;
        }
    }
    return index;
}


/* Code for part 3 goes here*/
int NextHighestSnow(double data[], int size, int Highest)
{
    int i;
    double secmax = -1;
    int arrayindex;

        for(i = 0; i > size; i++)
    {
        if(data[i] > secmax && data[i] < Highest) {
            secmax = data[i];
            arrayindex = i;
        }

    }
    return arrayindex;
}

/* Code for part 4 goes here*/

double Range (double data[], int size)
{
    double maxval = data[HighestSnow(data, size)];
    double min = data[0];

    int i;

    for(i = 1; i < size; i++)
    {
        if(min > data[i])
            min = data[i];
    }

    return maxval - min;
}
```

Problem: The total snowfall (in inches) in the state of Michigan over the last 20 years has been provided in
the file “snowfall.txt”. The file is formatted so that the first column is the year and the second column is the
snowfall in inches for that year. Write a program to obtain the following information:
1. What year was the greatest amount of snowfall and how much fell that year (in inches)?
2. What year was the 2nd highest total of snowfall and how much fell that year (in inches)?
3. What is the range of total snowfall in the last 20 years?
ALL printf statements MUST be in main() unless otherwise noted.
NOTE: Remember, you can verify your results with EXCEL.
Follow these detailed instructions:
1. First, read this document in its entirety.
2. Include the usual (detailed) comment block including program name, author, date, inputs, outputs and
description, followed by your preprocessor directives.
3. An outline (Skeleton-code) of the source code is shown below and you are REQUIRED to follow this
outline. You may write other supporting functions but you MUST have at least the 4 functions prototyped.
Insert appropriate printf statements where needed to get the desired output. The outline has four sections
where you are to enter in your code and complete the program.
a. Part 1: You are required to write the function ReadFile to open “snowfall.txt” for input and read
the data in that file into 2 arrays. Remember to check if file exists and not read past the EOF. The
error message if file does not exist can be in the function. The function will return the number of
data points in the file. NOTE: Remember, the data is in pairs with the first number being a year and
the second being a record of snowfall in inches. Print out the data in two columns from main().
b. Part 2: You are required to write the function called HighestSnow which accepts the array of
snowfall amounts, and a parameter named size which indicates the size of the array. This function
returns an integer indicating the array index number that corresponds to the highest snowfall. Print
out the year and amount of the highest snowfall from main().
c. Part 3: You are required to write the function call NextHighestSnow which accepts the array of
snowfall amounts, a parameter named size which indicates the size of the array, and an integer
named Highest indicating the index corresponding to the highest snowfall. This function returns
an integer indicating the array index number that corresponds to the 2nd highest snowfall. Print out
the year and amount of the second highest snowfall from main().
d. Part 4: You are required to write the function call Range which accepts the array of snowfall
amounts, and a parameter named size which indicates the size of the array. This function returns the
difference between the maximum and minimum snowfalls in the last 20 years. Remember, you can
call the function HighestSnow from the Range function. Print out the range of snowfall in
inches from main().
e. Part 5 (Extra Credit): Make your file name a user input, i.e. ask the user for the input file name.

```
OUTLINE OF THE SOURCE CODE:
//Block comment with name, date, program description
#include <stdio.h>
// include other header files that you need
#define MAX_SIZE 100 //can go back 100 years if necessary
int ReadFile (int data1[], double data2[]);
int HighestSnow (double data[], int size);
int NextHighestSnow (double data[], int size, int Highest);
double Range (double data[], int size);
int main (void) {
int Year[MAX_SIZE];
double Snow[MAX_SIZE],SnowfallRange;
int FileLength, IndexHighest, IndexNextHighest;
//Describe code
//Read file using function
FileLength = ReadFile(Year,Snow);
//Print out data in two columns with first being year and second
//being snowfall in inches
IndexHighest = HighestSnow(Snow,FileLength);
//Print out the year and amount of the highest snowfall
IndexNextHighest = NextHighestSnow(Snow, FileLength,IndexHighest);
//Print out the year and amount of the next highest snowfall
SnowfallRange = Range(Snow,FileLength);
//Print out the range of snowfall (Max-Min) in inches.
return 0;
}
//Code for part 1 goes here, include ALL error checks.
// Code for part 2 goes here
// Code for part 3 goes here
// Code for part 4 goes here
```

Comment: You can't create a 2d array with one `int` and one `double`. You need two 1d arrays or a struct. For example: `struct snowfall_data {int year; double amount;}`

Comment: Also, your program can be greatly simplified if you sort the data first.  You can use [`qsort()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/algorithm/qsort) for that.

Comment: This is technically an assignment and I'm supposed to write it a specific way.

Comment: That was left over from a previous assignment, I was using it to help me find where my issues with my code was at.

Answer (score 0):

I've gone through and pointed out the errors I found.

```
// Missing 3rd parameter
int NextHighestSnow (double data[], int size, int Highest);
// There is no 3rd parameter to range
double Range (double data[], int size);

int main (void)

{
    // This should not be 2d
    int Year[MAX_SIZE];
    ...
    // Don't use %d to print a double. Use %lf, %le, %lg
    printf("The year for the highest snowfall is: [%d] at %lg\n", Year[IndexHighest], Snow[IndexHighest]);
    ....
}

// Changed for 1d array
// Also, this should take a 3rd parameter for size....
int ReadFile (int data1[], double data2[])
{
    ....
    // Changed test to == 2. fscanf returns # of items successfully scanned
    // or EOF 
    for(i = 0; fscanf(f,"%d %lf ", &data1[i], &data2[i]) == 2; i++);
    ....
}

int HighestSnow(double data[], int size)
{
    ...
    double max = data [0];
    // Since you set max = data[0], loop can start at 1
    for (i = 1; i < size; i++)
    ....
}
// Added 3rd param
int NextHighestSnow(double data[], int size, int Highest)
{
    ...
    // Why search for min?

    // Can't initialize to data[0] in case data[0] is max
    // Use -1 since can't have negative snowfall
    double secmax = -1;  
    int arrayindex;

    for(i = 0; i > size; i++)
    {
        if(data[i] > secmax && data[i] < Highest) {
            secmax = data[i];
            arrayindex = i;
        }
    }

    return arrayindex;
}


double Range (double data[], int size)
{
    // Already have code to find max
    double maxval = data[HighestSnow(data, size)];
    double min = data[0];

    int i;

    for(i = 1; i < size; i++)
    {
        if(min > data[i])
            min = data[i];
    }

    return maxval - min;
}
```

Comment: So, I used your suggestions, and updated my code, but now I'm getting some new errors. I updated the new code in my main post.

Comment: updated my code some more, now I'm getting outputs that are repeated until I get to year with highest snow. I updated the new code in my main post, not sure what I took out that is causing this repeated loop...

Comment: @Galahad The `for(i = 0; i < FileLength; i++) printf("The year for the highest.....` loop in `main()` should be removed.